# Why do we only buffer the input in networking?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

So I learned recently that the standard [basic networking in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) goes like this:

```
out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
```

I just want to clarify, so for the output we don't use a `BufferedWriter` because that's the job on the server's side? Would it be wrong to do something like this:

```
out =  new BufferedWriter(PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true));
```

Comment: No one would seriously ever use `PrintWriter` for network I/O.

Comment: @BrianRoach  - That's a good point  , so what's used instead?

Comment: It depends on what it is you're doing. There's a number of wrappers you use depending on what it is you're writing and how you're writing. (Yes, that's vague, but there's no simple answer). `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))` for example, is probably pretty common for basic network I/O.

Comment: We do buffer the output. This is not the standard basic networking  in Java. PrintWriter buffers output. Not a real question.

Comment: @BrianRoach -  Thank You Very Much! I'll study up more then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Java documentation:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html
>
> Most of the examples we've seen so far use unbuffered I/O. This means each read or write request is handled directly by the
>   underlying OS. This can make a program much less efficient, since each
>   such request often triggers disk access, network activity, or some
>   other operation that is relatively expensive.
>
> To reduce this kind of overhead, the Java platform implements buffered I/O streams. Buffered input streams read data from a memory
>   area known as a buffer; the native input API is called only when the
>   buffer is empty. Similarly, buffered output streams write data to a
>   buffer, and the native output API is called only when the buffer is
>   full.

Yes, "buffered" input *AND* output is usually a Good Idea.

IMHO...

PS:

I don't see anything wrong with PrintWriter.  Especially if I wanted to do "printf()" style text I/O directly to the socket.

Comment: My point about `PrintWriter` is that it would not be common for you to be doing that in any real application.

Comment: Fair enough :).  But if I wanted to open a socket on port 80 and "printf()" my own HTTP headers and content manually - than "PrinterWriter" is probably how I'd do it.  There's nothing intrinsically "wrong" with PrintWriter.

Comment: be careful of line breaks though. HTTP requires \r\n, PrintWriter uses system default line break.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu - good point - thank you!

Comment: What a intrinsically wrong with both PrintWriter and PrintStream is that they swallow exceptions and provide no way of knowing what they were: just one bit of information saying that an exception occurred. This is not adequate in network programming. You need at least to be able to distinguish your own bugs (SocketClosedException, etc) from network problems, peer problems, ...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call that example "standard". It's a simple tutorial. It uses `BufferedReader` not for buffering, but for the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method.

For a serious application, yes, the output *should* be buffered. You should not write many pieces of small data. If nothing else, the overhead of system call for each write() is a killer.